# SSD Active time 100% when working in After Effects

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, resource-usage, adobe-after-effects

[image]I have a Patriot Viper M.2 VPN 100 for my system SSD, and I have the After Effects image cache installed there as well. After about 5 to 10 minutes of using After Effects the Active Time jumps to 100% and, for the most time, as long as i keep AE open, it stays that way, even when i'm not actively editing in the program. Needless to say, the whole PC takes a nose dive performance-wise, and i can't even properly navigate a web page. The transfer rate stays low throughout this process so i'm guessing there's a bug somewhere that makes the device go into overdrive.

The only partial fix i found for this is moving the AE cache to another drive, but that's a normal HDD. The Active Time problem stays the same, but because it's not a system drive, the PC performance is not affected. Still, it being a HDD makes AE much more slower, and it defeats most of the purpose of having a SSD in the first place.

Can anybody help me solve this problem? I know this is not a general issue, because on other PC's i don't see the same problem, even with AE having the cache on the system drive. And i don't see much info on the internet about this particular correlation.

I don't really know what other info to give, so if there's something that would help you figure out the problem, please ask.

LE: This happens on After Effects CC20 (17.7.0) and CC21 (18.0.0). Don't remember if it happened on prior versions, cause i was editing more from the office back then.

LE2: Maybe this helps, but another weird issue i noticed for a while, is that sometimes, when i'm playing a game, and try to save, the HDD chugs really hard, and the saving takes a few seconds more than it should. This happens only after i had the system running for some time, and done stuff on it. So, if i play the game right after startup, the saving process happens almost instantly. But if I play it in the evening, the saving takes some 15-30 seconds, and i hear the HDD chugging heavily.

LE3: I've attached a screenshot of Task Manager when the issue happens. This is made while working in AE, hence the Memory usage as well. The SSD in the picture is not the Viper i mentioned above, (that one is C:) but, as i said, the issue is the same on all the drives i move the AE Cache to.

Comment: BTW, worse than performance issue, SSD's have a finite number of writes. If that app is really churning the drive, particularly over the same files, it shortens the lifetime of the SSD.

Comment: Check the temperature of the SSD. If the SSD is getting too hot this can result in massive performance loss.

Comment: As with anything video-related, you really need a) a lot of RAM & b) your footage & proxies on a second drive, with your cache on a third. Trying to do it all on your boot drive is just asking for trouble, especially if it's a small drive. 1 or 2TB will still bottleneck badly, but won't wear itself quite so fast. 2 drives are essential, 3 is better still. Of course, being video, ie high data rate, all the drives need to be *fast*.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yeah, I'm aware of that, but that's not really the problem i have. As I said, most PC's i've worked on did have the cache on the System Drive, and while it might have been less optimal, speed wise, it didn't behave as bad as mine. And moving the cache to another drive doesn't solve the underlying problem: The disk drive that has the AE cache on it still jumps to 100% Active time, regardless if it's system or not.

Comment: I have a certain idea that this has to do with some faulty way my system allocates resources, in that *something* hangs up my storage device when certain conditions are met. But i don't have enough technical know how to track down the issue

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s Performance tab with the SSD selected when the issue occurs.

Comment: Done, attached it to the Original Post